# Next.js authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, next.js

I've implemented authentication and authorization in nextjs app but the problem is there that when I refresh the page or route to different page the state values going to default value and logged out the user

I have used context hook for persisting user values and database to store user info from next auth and using context hook for authorization and authentication